# Securing a REST service with no authentication

Tags: ios, rest

i am designing a REST service for an iOS app. I was wondering how i can make the RESt service secure so that only requests made from the iOS app is allowed?

I was thinking to use a shared secret but still have the problem where this is exposed if you inspect the request.

Another way is to use OAuth which is not a desired solution. I want to be able to authentiate in the actual request rather than exchanging token across several requests.

The only solution i can think of is a time based encrytion. The shared secret is encrypted on time based where at the server the request is only valid for a certain duration.

Answer (score 3):

Your requests won't be visible to sniffers if you transmit them over an SSL-protected protocol like HTTPS (and use a server certificate to guard against man-in-the-middle attacks), so a shared secret burned into the app could work.

Of course, if someone really wants to, they could reverse-engineer your app to find the secret stored within. If you're building something that connects to people's bank accounts, then don't bother. If you're just trying to add a small layer of protection to prevent trivial hacking or DDOS-ing of your service, then it sounds like a reasonable approach.

Comment: If you purchase a SSL certificate that is known to be trusted by iOS, then you can just install the certificate on your server and the https connections from iOS "will just work".  That makes life much easier and as Brian Kelly said, you only really have to worry about someone reversing your app to find the secret.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is indeed possible to work around, your best bet would be to use some kind of login mechanism, but that doesn't prevent someone attempting to spoof the app with authentication included.

You can't trust the client, but if you use something like OAuth you can at least deter people from trying. If the app uses in-app purchases, you could authenticate an account as having access, then follow that route. Other than that, however, there aren't any 'perfect' solutions, so to speak.